# How can I tell what version of eclipse I have?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to use the eclipse delta pack, and I need to use the same exact version of the delta pack as the version of eclipse I'm using. When looking at Help>About Eclipse I see:

Version: 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f

Build id: I20110613-1736

However, it seems the versions listed on the eclipse site have a different format. Here are the versions listed here: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

3.7RC4  Fri, 3 Jun 2011 -- 09:09 (-0400)

3.7RC3  Thu, 26 May 2011 -- 17:08 (-0400)

3.7RC2  Thu, 19 May 2011 -- 11:38 (-0400)

3.7RC1  Thu, 12 May 2011 -- 20:00 (-0400)

3.7M7   Thu, 28 Apr 2011 -- 08:48 (-0400)

3.7M6   Thu, 10 Mar 2011 -- 11:19 (-0500)

3.7M5   Thu, 27 Jan 2011 -- 20:34 (-0500)

3.7M4   Wed, 8 Dec 2010 -- 13:00 (-0500)

3.7M3   Thu, 28 Oct 2010 -- 14:41 (-0400)

3.7M2a  Tue, 21 Sep 2010 -- 10:24 (-0400)

3.7M1   Thu, 5 Aug 2010 -- 17:00 (-0400)

Which version do I use?

Comment: I think the build id string is the date, so 20110613 is June 13 2011. So your version is 3.7RC4

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it seems that was the only broken link on the page, so I'll have to try again with an older version of eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the latest version.

I would say you can go for 3.7RC4 Fri, 3 Jun 2011 -- 09:09 (-0400) looking at the Build id: I20110613-1736 - 2011 Jun 13 @17:36

Comment: Just try with the RC3 with your current version, should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have the latest 3.7 build.

**I20110613-1736** corresponds to **3.7 Mon, 13 Jun 2011 -- 17:36 (-0400)**

It is not in the list of archived downloads you posted.

If you want you can try the one which is closest to yours: **3.7RC4 Fri, 3 Jun 2011 -- 09:09 (-0400)**